# Can reordering commits with git interactive rebase cause a conflict?

Tags: git, version-control

When reordering commits with `git rebase -i`, is it possible to have a conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course.

Suppose "O" (original) looks like this:

```
 foo
 foo2
 common
 stuff
```

and change A looks like this:

```
 foo
+bar
 foo2
 common
 stuff
```

Now suppose change B looks like this:

```
 foo
 bar
-foo2
 common
 stuff
```

If they used to go in the order "make change A, then make change B" and you ask git to make change B without having made change A, git will see that the context is "`foo`, then `foo2`, then `common`, then `stuff`" which does not match the expected "`foo`, then `bar`, then `foo2`, then `common`, then `stuff`".

If you manually resolve that and go on to ask git to now apply change A, `foo2` will be missing, messing with *that* change's context.